# enable submit button ondrop event

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<div class="notRobot">
  <div id="div1"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <img id="drag1" src="CLC_logo.jpg" draggable="true"
  ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
  
 </div>
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Click Me!" disabled>
```

OK this is what I trying to do, I have a submit button that's disable, as a validation option I want to use the  drag and drop event to enable the button.

So when I drop the img into the box the submit button will be enable.

Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code and explain what problem you're having with it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla javascript:

```
//Vanilla javascript way of attaching events when document is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   //attach drop event to box 
   document.getElementById("yourBoxId").addEventListener("ondrop", function(){
       //re-enable submit button
       document.getElementById("yourSubmitButtonId").disabled = false;
   });
});
```

In JQuery, (if applicable)

```
//Use JQuery's document.ready to attach drop event to your box, then re-enable button for submit
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Attach drop event
    $('#yourBoxId').on('drop', function(){
        //Re-enable submit button
        $('#yourSubmitButtonId').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```